# AngularUI Router redirection to child state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Right now, I have a file upload interface that is made up of a main file selection state and a child file uploading state. I want to add some sort of logic that redirects the user to the child uploading state if a file is being uploaded. How is it possible to do this in UI Router?

I have seen a solution like this which is essentially a request interceptor (source: [AngularJS [UI-Router] urlRouteProvider.when() versus resolve for routing to child states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20481503/angularjs-ui-router-urlrouteprovider-when-versus-resolve-for-routing-to-chil))

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState) {
  if (toState.name === 'dashboard') {
    event.preventDefault();

    switch (myCondition) {
      case 1:
        $state.go('dashboard.splash');
        break;
      case 2:
        $state.go('dashboard.podSelector');
        break;
      default:
        $state.go('somewhereElse');
        break;
    }
  }
});
```

But I am not entirely convinced that this is actually the best way of doing this.

Comment: I also came up with the same strategy after struggling with it for some time. But, I'm also not convinced with the method. Let's see if anyone has anything to add.